# Flask-SQLAlchemy: SAWarning: Identity map already had an identity for (object), replacing it with newly flushed object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I've made a personal web server to scrape some sites and display the data on a web page. But when I try to commit the results to the database I got a warning for each Video that I commit. I'd like to know if this warning can be fixed or at least hidden ?

Here's my code:

```py
from web_scraper import db
from web_scraper.models import Video

old_db = Video.query.all() # existing database to compare with the new one
db_queue = list() # scraping results ready to be added to the database

### web scraping occurs here to fill db_queue

db.drop_all() # reset db
db.create_all() # recreate a new one
for vid in db_queue:
    db.session.add(vid) # adding all pending results
db.session.commit() # error thrown here
```

And here's the complete warning output:

```
C:\DevApps\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py:1948: SAWarning: Identity map already had
an identity for (<class 'web_scraper.models.Video'>, (2133,), None), replacing it with newly flushed object.
Are there load operations occurring inside of an event handler within the flush?
```

Comment: try doing `commit` before `db.create_all`

Comment: @sahasrara62 i got this error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: video`
http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This warning is issued because:

- A session is created
- Existing objects are fetched into the session
- The database tables are dropped and re-created
- New objects are added to *the same session*
- The new objects have the same ids as objects added to the original session, so SQLAlchemy warns that the original objects in the session are being overwritten with the new objects

The objects in `old_db` are still the original objects, so you could choose to ignore the warning, but it's usually best to deal with warnings before they lead to errors (that's why they're warnings).

You could take one or all of these steps:

- [close](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.close)* the original session and open a new one before adding the new objects
- [expunge](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.expunge_all) the objects from the session
- instead of dropping and recreating the tables, [delete](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#deleting-orm-objects-using-the-unit-of-work-pattern) the objects that they contain

---

* or [remove](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session.remove) if it's a `scoped_session`.

Comment: found this while tracking this warning for my `pytest` suite that tests my backend endpoints that use `FSA`.  If you make assert statements at the end of unit tests you need to close the session before letting pytest do teardown and subsequent setup for the next test (assuming you want them atomic and are working like I am here where you dont drop and recreate the entire database every time)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [snakecharmerb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585766/14819065)
This code helped me

1. close connection with the db
2. recreate the db
3. reestablish connection with the db

```py
db.session.close()
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
```

**Note: The database will be deleted with the data inside of it when executing this code.**